# DOM Element - Youtube videos

Tags: javascript, dom

I am implementing 4 different YouTube videos on the same page of my website using the code I found below.

I found a script that does not load the videos before you press play. It works very well. Credit to : Amit Agarwal.

I have one problem though, it loads the same thumbnail for every video and I have no idea how to change it. I have tried editing ID's and variables.

Im using AVADA in Wordpress and simply pasted the DOM code in each container with a different img src. That didnt work :-)

Any suggestions? Here is the code:

```
<script>

/* Light YouTube Embeds by @labnol */
/* Web: http://labnol.org/?p=27941 */

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        var div, n,
            v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
            div.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
            div.onclick = labnolIframe;
            v[n].appendChild(div);
        }
    });

function labnolThumb(id) {
    var thumb = '<img src="PATH_TO_IMAGE">',
        play = '<div class="play"></div>';
    return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
}

function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", this.dataset.id));
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

Comment: What is `PATH_TO_IMAGE`? How about giving us a working example, so that we can modify that code to determine how to help.

Comment: It is the url to the thumbnail image for the video. Here is the original code I found : https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/

Comment: return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play; <- this won't do anything. the string "ID" does not exist in the thumb variable. Therefore there is nothing to be replaced. You should show us how you are assigning the image paths. If this is the code, then this is one problem.

Comment: That is the code. I posted the link to it in my previous post. I guess as the code is now it will always show the same thumbnail